# Spring JPA specifications when having Many to Many relation

Tags: postgresql, spring-boot, hibernate, many-to-many

I have the following problem: I'm trying to use more than one specification in findAll() and it returns duplicate. Here is my code in the example below (Please correct me if you need more information). I'm using Hibernate6 and PostgreSQL database.

Entity A:

```
@Builder
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
@Getter
@Setter
@Entity
@Table(name = “entityA)
public class EntityA extends AbstractAggregateRoot<EntityA> {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    @UuidGenerator
    private UUID id;

    @Column
    private String name;


    @OneToMany(mappedBy = “entity”A, cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.LAZY, orphanRemoval = true)
    @Builder.Default
    private Set<EntityAB> abs = new HashSet<>();

    @ManyToMany(cascade = {
        CascadeType.PERSIST,
        CascadeType.MERGE
    })
    @JoinTable(name = “other_relation",
        joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = “entityA"),
        inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = “entityC”)
    )
    @Builder.Default
    private Set<OtherEntity> others = new HashSet<>();

    }
}
```

Entity AB (mapped M-N relation)

```
@Builder
@Embeddable
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
@Getter
@Entity
@EqualsAndHashCode(callSuper = true)
@Table(name = “entityAB”)
public class EntityAB extends AbstractAggregateRoot<EntityAB> {

    @EmbeddedId
    @Include
    private EntityABId entityAbId;

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER, optional = false)
    @MapsId(“entityAId”)
    @JoinColumn(name = “entityAid”)
    private EntityA entityA;

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER, optional = false)
    @MapsId(“entityBid”)
    @JoinColumn(name = “entityBId”)
    private EntityB entityB;

    @Column
    @Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
    private Status status ;

}
```

Entity B:

```
@Builder
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
@Getter
@Setter
@Entity
@Table(name = “entityB)
public class EntityB {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    @UuidGenerator
    private UUID id;

    @Column
    private String name;

    @Column
    private String link;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = “entityB”, cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.LAZY, orphanRemoval = true)
    private Set<EntityAB> abs;

    @ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade = {
        CascadeType.PERSIST,
        CascadeType.MERGE
    })
    @JoinTable(name = "other_relation",
        joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = “entityBId”),
        inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = “otherId”)
    )
    @Builder.Default
    private Set<OtherEntity> others = new HashSet<>();
```

So, when i use findAll with the following parameters, it returns duplicates

```
Page<EntityA> findAll(Specification<EntityA> specialAction, Pageable pageable);
```

This happens when I'm using "IN" operator and one EntityA matches with 2 or more EntityAB relation.

Specification in the example below:

```
public static Specification<EntityA> valueIn(List<EntityB> bs) {
    return (root, query, criteriaBuilder)
        -> {
        if (CollectionUtils.isEmpty(bs)) {
            return criteriaBuilder.conjunction();
        }

        return root.get(“abs”).get(“entityB”).get("id").in(bs.stream().map(EntityB::getId).collect(
            Collectors.toSet()));
    };
}
```

Invoking the method:

```
return entityAJpaRepo.findAll(emailLike(search).and(valueGreaterThan(value)).
and(valueIn(bs)),pageable)
```

Best regards